# Why My Grid Height Over Phone Size in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image: iOS Screen Simulator is IPhone 12 Pro MAX]

iOS Screen Simulator is IPhone 12 Pro MAX

[image: Android Screen Emulator is Pixel 3a XL]

Android Screen Emulator is Pixel 3a XL

```
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout x:Name="DetailStack" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" x:Name="DetailGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.7*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DcpTreeNode.Dcp.ValueType.Name}" Style="{StaticResource StyledContentLabel}" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}" BackgroundColor="Bisque"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DcpTreeNode.Dcp.Driver.Name}" Style="{StaticResource StyledContentLabel}" BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}" BackgroundColor="LawnGreen"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text=" : " Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DcpTreeNode.Dcp.Comment}" Style="{StaticResource StyledContentLabel}" BackgroundColor="LightGreen"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="" Style="{StaticResource StyledTitleLabel}" BackgroundColor="DeepPink"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding EnumValueList, Source={x:Reference PageInstance}}" SelectionMode="None"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--<ScrollView VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                
            </ScrollView>-->
        </Grid>
```

Above picture and code are my project

I was debug in my android phone result was in android it is good, but in iphone Grid was over phone screen size

i check what problem using scrollview

check result is so sad

in android phone my app ui is good work but in iphone my app ui is over screen size(scroll was created)

Why occured this happen? how to fix it?

[image]

This is to delete stacklayout

Comment: looking at your provided pictures everything seems normal, will u describe more what is the problem?

Comment: In short, the rendering results of android and ios are different.

Comment: you can see first row in android but ios is no

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in your problem. I use you code and run in iOS simulator iPhone 11 Pro Max and it works the same as Android. Are there any more relevant codes?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use a Grid inside a StackLayout and inside a Grid **if not neccessary**. It makes it easy for errors to occur. Do try to remove the StackLayout. I think your problem is using the StackLayout. Besides that, it may be based on your defined styles.

Comment: i delete stacklayout but it was not solution, 
Could it be the resolution of my computer and iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout nesting is: Grid#1 ( StackLayout ( Grid#2 (Grid#3) ) ).

There is no way for Grid#2 (the inner grid) to know that those `Height="0.1*"` are supposed to be a fraction of the phone's height.

Remove BOTH Grid#1 AND StackLayout.

While it isn't the cause of your problem, you also don't need Grid#3. You can reduce this entire layout to a SINGLE Grid:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="1*, 1*, 1*, 7*" ColumnDefinitions="25*,5*,70*"
          RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Test 00" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="01" BackgroundColor="Green" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Test 02" BackgroundColor="Red" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Test 10" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="11" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Test 12" />

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Test 20" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="21" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Test 22" />

        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Test 30" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="31" BackgroundColor="Green" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Test 32" BackgroundColor="Red" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Grid Fill Screen]

---

For iOS, make sure page is rendering to "iOS Safe Area":

App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             x:Class="TestBugs.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="ios:Page.UseSafeArea" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[image: XF Grid w iOS SafeArea]